# Storm Spout and Bolts not autowiring Dependencies using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-storm

I am building a Storm topology with set of Spouts and Bolts  and also using Spring for Dependency Injection .

Unfortunately , none of my fields are getting autowired even though I have declared all my spouts and Bolts as @Components .

However the place where I am declaring my topology , Spring is working fine and all dependencies are getting injected properly .

Is it because cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology())  submits the topology to a cluster (locally it spawns different thread for Spouts and Bolts) that Autowiring is not working?

Please suggest .

PS -> I am using annotation based Configurations as opposed to xml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this but no one directed me to correct answer. Posting it so that it is useful for somebody :

Spouts and Bolts cannot resolve Dependencies as they are created as new Objects by ToplogyBuilder

For ex:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("rabbitMqSpout", new RabbitListnerSpout(), 1);
    builder.setBolt("mapBolt", new GroupingBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("rabbitMqSpout");
    builder.setBolt("reduceBolt", new PublishingBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("mapBolt");
```

The moment you create them using new , they are out of the scope of Spring's Context . One can solve this by sending applicationContext as constructor .

So You can have it as ,

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("rabbitMqSpout", new RabbitListnerSpout(appContext), 1);
    builder.setBolt("mapBolt", new GroupingBolt(appContext), 1).shuffleGrouping("rabbitMqSpout");
    builder.setBolt("reduceBolt", new PublishingBolt(appContext), 1).shuffleGrouping("mapBolt");
```

This way it is available to spouts and bolts . So when u start ur cluster they are still available .

P.S-> I have only tested on LocalCluster .

Update , the above will not work on remote Cluster as appContext cant be serialized . To make spring work on remote Cluster , one will have to define and initialize Context within open and prepare methods of Spouts and Bolts .